# Drupal 8 How to create custom block in a theme

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have created a custom theme and added regions. I want to create and assign a custom block to the regions. How can I do it?

As an experimental purpose I have created a folder named 'blocks' in path /themes/custom_theme/templates and named the block 'block--regionname.twig.html'. But no hope. Please advice. I think i'm on a wrong track.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your "custom block" in template in your theme, that not will be available in the Block layout page in your Drupal site and you can't place it to a region.

You can create custom blocks in Structure -> Block Layout -> Add custom block.
Or you can create it from custom module.
These will be available in the Block Layout page, and you can place into a region. You can define twig template for your block in your custom module, and you can write HTML into it.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block